# Using alarm() to implement process timeout

Tags: c++, timeout, fork, alarm

I am trying to make a mechanism that will wait for a child process for a specified amount of time and perform additional actions accordingly.

I have tried the following:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>

volatile sig_atomic_t p_flag = false;

pid_t makeproc ()
{
  pid_t pid;

  pid = fork();

  // parent
  if (pid) return pid;

  //child 
  std::cout << "Child created\n";
  sleep(5);
  exit(0);
}

void sig_handle (int sig)
{
  std::cout << "Handler called\n"; 
  p_flag = true;
}

int main() {
  int status;
  pid_t child;
  int ret;

  signal (SIGALRM, sig_handle);
  alarm(2);

  child = makeproc();
  pid_t p = waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
  std::cout << "PID: " << p << " FLAG: " << p_flag;

  return 0;
}
```

What I get out of this, is that `waitpid()` is not interrupted by the `SIGALRM` and the parent continues to wait until the process finishes. The output shows that `SIGALRM` is generated and handler is called.

```
Child created
Handler called
PID: 31683 FLAG: 1
```

I can't perform `kill()` in the handler to kill the child. How can I get `wait()` to return when `SIGALRM` is raised?

Comment: This is not C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, in your version of OS, `signal` call installs handler with `SA_RESTART` flag set. When this flag is set, system calls are automatically restarted after signal handler.

To take control of this, instead of using obsolete and deprecated `signal`, use `sigaction`, and make sure to not specify SA_RESTART flag. This should fix your issue.